# Android Studio (3.3.1) on Windows platform Theme Editor did not work?

Tags: android, themes, editor

Recently, Android studio (3.3.1) latest update on Windows cannot find the "Theme Editor". Even I can find it in Settings, there is nothing exist. But the MacOS appear as usual.

Hope you guys can help me or advise any solution to this problem. Thank you so much.